# Selecting Sql Data Source Column Value to Variable (VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, web-applications

I have a `SqlDataSource`, defined in the Master Page, that gets the current user permissions for the `web application` `Select * from portal_users where userid = @userid`, where `portal_users` is a view i built with all the data needed. I need to access the contents on the returned row so I can disable/enable site features according to the user permissions. This results in a lot of `if` blocks across the child pages to do it.

I browsed around forums and I only found issues about assigning those values to controls like i.e. `label`. Is there a way to access the `SqlDataSource` from the `Master Page`, get the row that is returned, select 1 or more column's values and assign them to variables?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hy
It's not a good idea, use Master Page to share Data Source connections
Read this post to help you:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1188088.aspx?sql+data+source+in+Master+Page

Regards